# How do I get the state of a checkbox in a MDL table?

Tags: javascript, material-design-lite

I generate the table from user inputted data, the user can change the data after the page has loaded and I have to adjust the checkboxes accordingly (regenerating the code)

I'm trying to:

- Call a JS function when a checkbox is ticked
- Be able to get states of every one checkbox individually (list of all checkboxes and their values also applicable)
- Set the values of every individual checkbox

I didn't see a way to do it, because in the source code, there are no checkboxes - only the table setting. Thus, I'm unable to set every individual checkbox its ID.

I wonder, is it possible to: get the code that is generated when the browser loads my page and the code the JS generates and serve it to straight from the server generated, but with individual IDs for every checkbox? In this case, how would I get the state of a checkbox?

If anything is unclear, feel free to ask for details.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the mdl-data-table--selectable class. Instead, refer to https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/Deprecations#automatic-selection-checkboxes . It's already compatible with the actual MDL version, but in version 2 there will be ripples for these buttons...

(I myself finally solved the problem by avoiding tables and cooking a list class and using list for my information.)

Answer (score 0):

A row is cheked when it has the class is-selected:

```
<tr class="is-selected">

</tr>
```

You can get and set the check state in Javascript by toggling this class.